# How could I sort these values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sorting

I am trying to do a classement for my website in express but for that i would like to sort my value from the most to least like:

```
user123: 0
user987: 4
user769: 3
```

and after get:

```
user987: 4
user769: 3
user123: 0
```

for that i've tried

```
classement.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.val - b.val;
})
```

but it didn't work with `classement.sort is not a function` as error

this is what my json look like:

```
{
  '60e300f77c30186d545b2db3': 5,
  '60e301c4fc57814fd008017c': 2,
  '60e4439ea4025957366959f6': 10,
  '60e443bda402595736695a26': 4
}
```

Comment: `.sort` works on arrays, not objects. Convert your JSON response to an array.

Comment: and there is no `.val` available

Comment: uh i forgot to edit this but thx @zhulien it worked !

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to invoke the array method `.sort` on an object. You have to convert your JSON response to an array first. Also, as your object entities have different key names you'll have to do some additional mapping in order to handle it properly. You don't have a `val` property.

Also, your sorting function should be reversed as you want to sort descending.

Take a look at this solution and modify it as you see fit:

```
const jsonResponse = {
  '60e300f77c30186d545b2db3': 5,
  '60e301c4fc57814fd008017c': 2,
  '60e4439ea4025957366959f6': 10,
  '60e443bda402595736695a26': 4
};

const array = [];

Object.entries(jsonResponse).forEach(item => array.push({
  key: item[0],
  value: item[1]
}));

array.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.value - a.value;
});
```

Comment: there isn't really a reason to do that anyways, as it auto-sorts after you set the object.

Comment: @Jake Auto-sorts what?

Comment: I mean the object

Comment: @Jake I don't get what you're saying. Can you explain, please?

Comment: I mean, the `sortedArray` object is the same thing as the object you began with

Comment: @Jake If you mean the `sortedArray` is the same as `array` - yes. I am still not sure what you mean by `the object you began with` as that should be the JSON response.